# How can I custom Route::resource on the laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, resources

If my routes like this :

```
Route::prefix('member')->middleware('auth')->group(function(){
    Route::prefix('purchase')->group(function(){
        Route::get('order', 'Member\PurchaseController@order')->name('member.purchase.order');
        Route::get('transaction', 'Member\PurchaseController@transaction')->name('member.purchase.transaction');
    });
    Route::resource('purchase', 'Member\PurchaseController');
});
```

If I call : http://my-app.test/member/purchase/1, it works. No error

But I change my routes like this :

```
 Route::prefix('member')->middleware('auth')->group(function(){
    Route::prefix('purchase')->group(function(){
        Route::get('order', 'Member\PurchaseController@order')->name('member.purchase.order');
        Route::get('transaction', 'Member\PurchaseController@transaction')->name('member.purchase.transaction');
        Route::resource('/', 'Member\PurchaseController');
    });
 });
```

If I call : http://my-app.test/member/purchase/1, there exist error like this :

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

I'm using Laravel 5.6.
How can I solve this error?

Comment: show us what `php artisan route:list` gives

Comment: "_How can I solve this error?_" Revert your changes. You removed the prefix `Route::prefix('member')` from your route, so it should no longer be available via `/member/`. Your "new" url should probably be http://my-app.test/purchase/1

Comment: @kerbholz I had update my question

Comment: this won't work, resource routing need a name

Comment: Your first approach is good why you want like second approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
 Route::prefix('member')->middleware('auth')->group(function(){
  Route::prefix('purchase')->group(function(){
  Route::resource('/', 'Member\PurchaseController');  
  Route::get('order', 'Member\PurchaseController@order')->name('member.purchase.order');
  Route::get('transaction', 'Member\PurchaseController@transaction')->name('member.purchase.transaction');   
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`php artisan api:route`

Run this command in your root folder. It will list you all the routes you have defined . Check which route is displaying with the use of resource.